# Allow native code to directly access objects in java heap?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, jna, native-code

I have an array of objects in Java and I want to allow native C code direct access to that array (no copying or accessor functions). Is this possible? I don't mind if the solution is JVM-specific.

Comment: What do you want to do when the GC moves the object?

Comment: @SLaks: if the VM provided this ability then I suppose it would not relocate the array data during the period where the JNI code has access. IIRC you basically need one reference count per array in order to implement "do not relocate right now".

Comment: @SteveJessop - do you know of any mainstream JVM that does this in practice?  I imagine it would have a significant performance cost for the GC.  For a start, copying collection algorithms are problematic.

Comment: @StephenC: >Net does this (see pinning)

Comment: @StephenC: I don't know the state of the art regarding `GetIntArrayElements`, hence my careful use of "if" ;-) But for that matter does anyone use unconditional copying garbage collection for Java? My instinct is that repeatedly copying long-lived objects is a bad idea. If arrays have to be treated as "old" instead of "young" while they're pinned, and only "young" objects are copy-collected then I doubt that would cripple a VM. Once some objects are deemed not worth relocating, pinning a few more should be no big deal although of course they contribute to fragmentation.

Comment: @SteveJessop - you can't just "treat it as old".  An efficient copying collector works by copying ALL live objects to the "to" space ... no exceptions.  If you have to make exceptions 1) the algorithm is more complicated / expensive, and 2) allocation of new objects in the partly evacuated "from" space is more complicated / expensive.  And of course there is the fragmentation issue.  These overheads won't "cripple" the GC, but they will have a measurable effect ... and you don't want to have to pay for the possibility of pinning in JNI in every Java program.

Comment: @Slaks - 1) at what cost ...  2) Net isn't Java

Comment: @StephenC: 1) There is a perf cost.  2) I know; I was just providing an example.

Comment: @SLaks - well in the Java case, they have chosen to not support "pinning" (in mainstream JVMs) because of the performance impact on the storage management as a whole.  In Java, you have the choice of the `getXxxArrayElements` method that (typically) creates a copy of the array elements, or using a direct buffer as an array which results in the "array" being allocated outside of the heap.

Comment: @StephenC: that's why I asked: does anyone use unconditional copying garbage collection for Java? If they do, then of course all objects are treated alike. Another possibility would be to allocate arrays off a different space from other objects, so that when you copy-collect your "normal" space, the arrays are excluded. I suppose it's just a question of whether there's demand for pinning arrays -- if it's literally only user1622959 who wants it in Java (and there's more demand in .Net for whatever reasons), then clearly there's no point slowing down Java GC by so much as a microsecond.

Comment: @SteveJessop - I don't know what you mean by "unconditional copying garbage collection", but AFAIK no JVM uses any form of object pinning with copying collection.  Is that clear enough?

Comment: @StephenC: Wouldn't that (no support for pinning in JVMs) imply that the answer to my question would be: 'No, not possible'. From what I can tell, pinning would be the first requirement to allow access to the memory location(s) where the content of an object is stored in the java heap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer. It is generally not possible to do what I wanted with JNI. However, some VMs provide the needed functionality, I used JikesRVM:

1) The native code needs the memory location of the array. This can be achieved using the 'Magic' facility in JikesRVM, it provides an ObjectReference and an Address class that allow to obtain a memory address for each object. This address can then be forwarded to the native code as long/int argument (using JNI) and there casted to a pointer.

2) The GC may not move objects around. This is a bit more tricky since it requires support for pinning in the GC. In the case of JikesRVM, objects can be annotated with @NonMoving and @NonMovingAllocation (also part of 'Magic'). Furthermore, objects (i.e. arrays) > 8KB are placed in a Large Object Space, which doesn't move objects around.

Answer (score 2):

of course it is possible with JNI.

It's worth consulting this link : http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/array.html
in short -

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "IntArray.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL 
Java_IntArray_sumArray(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jintArray arr)
{
  jsize len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, arr);
  int i, sum = 0;
  jint *body = (*env)->GetIntArrayElements(env, arr, 0);
  for (i=0; i<len; i++)
    sum += body[i];
  (*env)->ReleaseIntArrayElements(env, arr, body, 0);
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Under the hood that copies the array elements.

Comment: @Samuel I doesn't do. It returns the pointer to array in the heap, and you can do whatever you like. UPD: it might copy items, but likely it will pin down the array, so it will not be moved by GC. Your solution with bytebuffer is better.

Comment: In most JVM's, it does a copy and returns a pointer to the copy. That's why you have to call ReleaseIntArrayElements for changes to the array done in Native code to be seen in Java. Check out http://elliotth.blogspot.com/2007/03/optimizing-jni-array-access.html

Comment: @Samuel, perhaps this is acceptable in topicstarter case. It's better to choose betweed several approaches than stick with single one :)

Comment: That's very true! I would suggest your solution unless OP really doesn't want to copy

Comment: GetPrimitiveArrayCritical would do what I need for primitive types without first copying them. However, I need the same kind of access to arrays of objects instead of primitives.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using newer versions of java, use [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) objects.

Call `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()` to allocate the buffer. The direct buffer lies outside the garbage collector's domain. To access the buffer from JNI, call [`GetDirectBufferAddress()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/jni-14.html#GetDirectBufferAddress). It returns a pointer to the byte buffer. This will do no copying under the hood. The changes to the buffer will be seen on the Java and Native side.

The javadocs have some warnings about using direct buffers:

> A direct byte buffer may be created by invoking the allocateDirect factory method of this class. The buffers returned by this method typically have somewhat higher allocation and deallocation costs than non-direct buffers. The contents of direct buffers may reside outside of the normal garbage-collected heap, and so their impact upon the memory footprint of an application might not be obvious. It is therefore recommended that direct buffers be allocated primarily for large, long-lived buffers that are subject to the underlying system's native I/O operations. In general it is best to allocate direct buffers only when they yield a measureable gain in program performance.

Comment: This implies that I have to iterate over the array first and copy the content of each object primitive-at-a-time into the byte buffer, correct? I was more hoping for a solution where I can interact with the objects in java, then without any copying interact with them in C and later interact with them in java again. So the native code should have direct access to the (pinned) array and use metadata that has been created in java (via reflection) to access the correct parts of memory. Is something like that possible? In a specific JVM?

Comment: A byte array is a way to store binary data, so you can store anything you want in a byte array. With objects it will be tougher because you need a way to serialize/deserialize the object from binary data (which will often involve copying). I think maybe you should use the copy method @jdevelop discussed. Every time you call ReleaseObjectArrayElements, those objects will update on the Java side. And as far as I know there is no easy way to access Java objects in C besides using the provided JNI methods to invoke methods on the Java object or read/write fields on the Java object.

Answer (score 0):

All of above question, there is a good solution(click below link):

[GetDirectBufferAddress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707653/how-do-i-call-multiple-data-types-from-getdirectbufferaddress-in-jni)

You can find how u can provide direct access if you have an object instead of primitive array.