# How do I call multiple data types from GetDirectBufferAddress in JNI?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I get a `bytebuffer` via the native methods.

The `bytebuffer` starts with 3 `int`s, then contains only doubles.
The third `int` tells me the number of doubles that follow.

I am able to read the first three `int`s.

Why is the code crashing when I try to read the doubles?

Relevant code to get the first three integers:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL test(JNIEnv *env, jobject bytebuffer)
{
   int * data = (int *)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(bytebuffer);
}
```

Relevant code to get the remaining doubles:

```
double * rest = (double *)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(bytebuffer + 12);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your posted code, you are calling this:

```
double * rest = (double *)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(bytebuffer + 12);
```

This adds 12 to the `bytebuffer` `jobject`, which not a number.

`GetDirectBufferAddress()` returns an address; since the first 3 `int` are 4 bytes each, I believe you are correctly adding 12, but **you are not adding it in the right place**.

What you probably meant to do is this:

```
double * rest = (double *)((char *)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(bytebuffer) + 12);
```

For your overall code, to get the initial three `int`s and the remaining `double`s, try something similar to this:

```
void * address = env->GetDirectBufferAddress(bytebuffer);
int * firstInt = (int *)address;
int * secondInt = (int *)address + 1;
int * doubleCount = (int *)address + 2;
double * rest = (double *)((char *)address + 3 * sizeof(int));

// you said the third int represents the number of doubles following
for (int i = 0; i < doubleCount; i++) {
    double d = *rest + i; // or rest[i]
    // do something with the d double
}
```

Comment: You need to perform (char *)-based pointer arithmetic not (double *)-based, at least until you get a pointer to the double array—then you can just add `i`.

Comment: Firstly, excuse me for such a late reply !!!
Direct (double *) did not work... as JoshDM mentioned...
I even tried to typecast to byte * and then to double * which also did not work...
Tomorrow I will try what TomBlodget has mentioned which I guess should work ... what logic says...I am currently outside....
Thanks to both Tom and Josh...